# Deploying the Microsoft Report Viewer as a Prerequisite in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce, reportviewer, bootstrapper, prerequisites

When I try to include the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime as a prerequisite in a ClickOnce deployment in VS2012, I receive the following warning:

> The 'Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime' item selected requires
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLSysClrTypes.11.0'.  Select the missing
>   prerequisite in the Prerequisites Dialog Box or create a bootstrapper
>   package for the missing prerequisite.

First of all, there are two prerequisite options for the SQLSysClrtypes - a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version.  Which one do I include?

Also, no matter which one I select, I receive the error:

> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi' for item 'Microsoft System CLR
>   Types for SQL Server 2012 (x86)' to your local machine.

However, I cannot seem to locate a redistributable package file for this.

Which version of these SQL CLR types do I need to include and where do I get the bootstrapper package?

**Update**

I found a MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx), and under the section that discusses ClickOnce publishing, it explicitly states:

> "Make sure that the Download prerequisites from the component vendor’s
>   website option is checked. This is the only supported option."

This seems a little crazy since not every computer has Internet access -- definitely not in my organization.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What's even better is that I only changed it _to_ download from same as my app, because of this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/a6169f1d-cf84-4375-a390-7814c42fef4b/ (which isn't limited to Vista, btw).  Deploying the Report Viewer is always a PITA.

Comment: This link help solve my issues, hope it helps you too. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd6ecd3b-e778-48f3-8038-fa243bd85987/visual-studio-2012-problem-with-report-viewer